# Use Pi as DLNA server and serve media from NAS

Tags: media-server

I have an old NAS (Xtreamer eTrayz) which does not have DLNA server. It is not supported anymore (the manufacturer does not exist, there is no community, all download links are broken), and I can't install any software on it (not with my level on embeded Linux knowledge at least)

Now I want to serve media to my TV, so figured out I need to get hardware media player which would act as DLNA server and take the files from my NAS.

Can Raspberry Pi play this role? I know that it's possible to use it as DLNA server serving media from attached flash drive, but it it possible for it to serve media from network storage?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `minidlna` in the Raspbian repository. In it's `/etc/minidlna.conf` you can specify the directories:

```
# Path to the directory you want scanned for media files.
#
# This option can be specified more than once if you want multiple directories
# scanned.
#
# If you want to restrict a media_dir to a specific content type, you can
# prepend the directory name with a letter representing the type (A, P or V),
# followed by a comma, as so:
#   * "A" for audio    (eg. media_dir=A,/var/lib/minidlna/music)
#   * "P" for pictures (eg. media_dir=P,/var/lib/minidlna/pictures)
#   * "V" for video    (eg. media_dir=V,/var/lib/minidlna/videos)
#   * "PV" for pictures and video (eg. media_dir=PV,/var/lib/minidlna/digital_camera)
#media_dir=/var/lib/minidlna
```

It should be possible to specify here network shares instead of local directories.